# Cancel alt + down arrow: remaining effect from VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table with page field. I wrote a few lines of code under the Pivot Table update event to do something.

When the page field filter is used via the keyboard, the filter form is accessed with the shortcut alt + down arrow typed on a page field cell.

Code works fine and at end moves focus to a specific cell.

Problem is that `alt + down` arrow effect remains! The cell is shown with a drop down list displayed and the operator needs to hit the escape key to continue working. I try to avoid this by adding a sendkeys {esc} line after, but the  sendkeys numlock bug is more annoying than having to directly hit the escape key.

My question is:

**Is there another way to close, using vba code, the drop down list displayed in final cell?**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

       Sheet1.ListObjects("precomanda").Resize Range(Sheet1.ListObjects("precomanda").HeaderRowRange, _
       Sheet1.ListObjects("precomanda").HeaderRowRange.Offset(Sheet1.PivotTables("Istoric").PivotFields("Produs").DataRange.Count, 0))
    Sheet1.Range("A5").Activate
    Application.SendKeys ("{ESC}")
End Sub
```

[image: remanent effect of alt down arrow]

Comment: Drop down list isn't generate by code!
If operator select filter sign with mouse problem is not appear. Only if operator choose to display filter form by keyboard I have this behavior.
I don't know how to add code :( in comment, sorry

Comment: The code for the shortcut alt + down arrow ?

Comment: shortcut alt+down arrow is a Excel built in shortcut

Comment: The filter form is accessed by the shortcut, this  is revealing the dropdown and it is this you can't get rid of?

Comment: Exact!
In first phase operator move focus to C1 cell (page field cell). Then he press 'alt+down' arrow shortcut to reveal filter form. Make him selection and hit 'Enter'.
Macro resize a table to fit pivottable length and move focus to first cell in databody of table. Issue is that drop down remain displayed!